# Button is not displaying in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, button, sass

I am using a button that triggers 4-5 other buttons with animation. its working fine in Chrome but not in FireFox

I have used a fullscreen background video in my current project, with this button, but in firefox, when i inspect elements, it shows there, but the browser is not displaying the element at all.

inspiration taken by - http://codepen.io/phenax/

```js
'use strict';
(function (document, win) {
    var animation_time = 600;
    var btn_move_limit = 30;
    var item_showing = false;
    var className = {
        show_items: 'menu--list__show',
        revolve: 'menu--list__revolve',
        button_cross: 'bar__crossy'
    };
    var $el = {
        toggle_btn: document.querySelector('.js-menu--toggle'),
        menu_items: document.querySelector('.js-menu--list'),
        items: document.querySelectorAll('.js-item')
    };
    var constrain = function constrain(val, lim) {
        return val > lim ? lim : val < -lim ? -lim : val;
    };
    var setButtonPosition = function setButtonPosition(left, top) {
        $el.toggle_btn.style.left = constrain(left, btn_move_limit) + 'px';
        $el.toggle_btn.style.top = constrain(top, btn_move_limit) + 'px';
    };
    var showAllItems = function showAllItems() {
        var item_menu = $el.menu_items.classList;
        item_menu.add(className.show_items);
        setTimeout(function () {
            item_menu.add(className.revolve);
            $el.toggle_btn.classList.add(className.button_cross);
            item_showing = true;
        }, animation_time);
    };
    var hideAllItems = function hideAllItems() {
        var item_menu = $el.menu_items.classList;
        item_menu.remove(className.revolve);
        $el.toggle_btn.classList.remove(className.button_cross);
        setTimeout(function () {
            item_menu.remove(className.show_items);
            item_showing = false;
            setButtonPosition(0, 0);
        }, animation_time);
    };
    var findPosRelative = function findPosRelative(e) {
        e = e.pageX ? {
            pageX: e.pageX,
            pageY: e.pageY
        } : e.touches[0];
        var offset = {
            x: win.innerWidth / 2,
            y: win.innerHeight / 2
        };
        e.pageX = e.pageX - offset.x;
        e.pageY = e.pageY - offset.y;
        return e;
    };
    var menuBtnClickHandler = function menuBtnClickHandler() {
        if (item_showing)
            hideAllItems();
        else
            showAllItems();
    };
    var itemClick = function itemClick(e) {
        var item_id = e.target.dataset.id;
        console.log('Item ID: ' + item_id);
        hideAllItems();
    };
    var mouseMoveMent = function mouseMoveMent(e) {
        var left, top;
        if (item_showing) {
            e = findPosRelative(e);
            left = 140 * e.pageX / win.innerWidth;
            top = 140 * e.pageY / win.innerHeight;
        } else {
            left = 0;
            top = 0;
        }
        setButtonPosition(left, top);
    };
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        $el.toggle_btn.addEventListener('click', menuBtnClickHandler);
        for (var i = 0; i < $el.items.length; i++) {
            if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
                break;
            }
            $el.items[i].addEventListener('click', itemClick);
        }
        window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
        win.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveMent);
        win.addEventListener('touchmove', mouseMoveMent);
    });
}(document, window));
```

```
.menu--toggle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: #222;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url("../images/logo/logo.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: -80px;
  filter: url("#svgFilter"); }
  .menu .item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #FFEB3B;
    color: #222; }
  .menu .item {
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out; }
  .menu--toggle {
    transition: all .2s linear; }
    .menu--toggle .bar {
      width: 20px;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: #222;
      margin: 5px auto;
      transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out; }
    .menu--toggle.bar__crossy .bar:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0; }
    .menu--toggle.bar__crossy .bar:nth-child(1) {
      transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg); }
    .menu--toggle.bar__crossy .bar:nth-child(3) {
      transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(-45deg); }
  .menu--list ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; }
  .menu--list li {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%; }
  .menu--list__show .item {
    margin-left: 60px; }
  .menu--list__revolve li:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(90deg); }
    .menu--list__revolve li:nth-child(1) .item {
      transform: rotate(270deg); }
  .menu--list__revolve li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(180deg); }
    .menu--list__revolve li:nth-child(2) .item {
      transform: rotate(180deg); }
  .menu--list__revolve li:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(270deg); }
    .menu--list__revolve li:nth-child(3) .item {
      transform: rotate(90deg); }
  .menu--list__revolve li:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotate(360deg); }
    .menu--list__revolve li:nth-child(4) .item {
      transform: rotate(0deg); }
```

```html
 <div class="menu">
                    <nav class="menu--list js-menu--list">
                        <ul>
                            <li><button type="button" onClick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/themadhousecafe', '_blank')" class="fa fa-facebook item js-item" data-id="1"></button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" onClick="window.open('http://blog.nomadbaker.com/', '_blank')" class="fa item js-item" data-id="2">Blog</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" onClick="window.open('#', '_blank')" class="item js-item" data-id="3">Menu</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" onClick="window.open('#', '_blank')" class="fa fa-phone item js-item" data-id="4"></button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <button type="button" class='logo_button menu--toggle js-menu--toggle'>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="bar"></div>

                    </button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Is it showing any error in console?

Comment: Yes, it is showing now, window.CP is undefined

Comment: Still stuck with this? or solved the issue?

Comment: still stuck with it, its just not showing in mozilla FF only, i am thinking of changing the whole idea

Comment: Have you tried same code by only removing 'use strict'; ???

Comment: Your error says window.CP is undefined, and in code I can't see that variable/object is initialized, you need to initialize that object ... is there a code which you haven't pasted here where window.CP is declared?

Comment: cause error simply says that you need to declare window.CP and then it's methods aswell

Comment: Yup, i dint just give a thought too it, the actual code was in babel, and i dint worked on initializing the last section of code.

Comment: Thanks @ParagBhayani